# Custom Error Message Does Not Display When Redirected If Session Expire

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hmvc

I am working on my login controller with **Codeigniter Version 3.0.3 and HMVC**

When the user logs on to the admin dashboard it sets a session token and then redirects it to url

```
http://localhost/projectname/admin/common/dashboard/?token=bf9691a625fbd0c3513ad822b0f76c6efb45e9b535c7b732d1ff006ce17f8734
```

> When the session expires it redirects back to the admin page And should display message on login page. I am
>   trying to set a **$data variable** message instead of using flash data

For some reason when session expires and gets redirected back to admin the warning message does not activate.

**Question:** Why does the custom data message not show up when session expires once redirected back to admin login?

I also use codeigniter hook function to run the **login check function**

**Controller**

Filename: Login.php

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends MX_Controller {

    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $data['title'] = 'Administration';

        $data['heading_title'] = 'Administration';

        if (($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {

            $this->load->library('encryption');

            $token =  bin2hex($this->encryption->create_key(32));

            $this->session->set_userdata(array('token' => $token));

            redirect('admin/common/dashboard/?token=' . $token);
        }

        // Message Below Not Display On Login If Session Expire And Has Been Redirected Back To Admin
        if ((isset($_SESSION['token']) && !isset($_GET['token'])) || ((isset($_GET['token']) && (isset($_SESSION['token']) && ($_GET['token'] != $_SESSION['token']))))) {
            $this->error['warning'] = 'Your Session Token Is Invalid!';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index', $data);
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');

        $this->load->view('common/login', $data);

    }


    protected function validate() {
        if (!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password']) || !$this->user->login($_POST['username'], html_entity_decode($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))) {
            $this->error['warning'] = 'Incorrect Username Or Password!';
        }

        return !$this->error;
    }

    public function check() {
        $uri_route = $this->uri->segment(2) .'/'. $this->uri->segment(3);

        $route = isset($uri_route) ? $uri_route : '';

        $ignore = array(
            'common/login',
            'common/forgotten',
            'common/reset'
        );

        if (!$this->user->is_logged() && !in_array($route, $ignore)) {
            redirect('admin/common/login');
        }

        if (isset($route)) {
            $ignore = array(
                'common/login',
                'common/logout',
                'common/forgotten',
                'common/reset',
                'error/not_found',
                'error/permission'
            );

            if (!in_array($route, $ignore) && (!isset($_GET['token']) || !isset($_SESSION['token']) || ($_GET['token'] != $_SESSION['token']))) {
                redirect('admin/common/login');
            }

        } else {

            if (!isset($_GET['token']) || !isset($_SESSION['token']) || ($_GET['token'] != $_SESSION['token'])) {
                redirect('admin/common/login');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Login View $error_warning**

```
<?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Hook**

```
<?php

$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => 'Login',
        'function' => 'check',
        'filename' => 'Login.php',
        'filepath' => 'modules/admin/controllers/common'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you never set that messsage. Your session has expired, and your if has two parts.

First part: `(isset($_SESSION['token']) && !isset($_GET['token']))`: session has expired, the token is not set in session, so the first condition is false.

And the second, beefy condition: `((isset($_GET['token']) && (isset($_SESSION['token']) && ($_GET['token'] != $_SESSION['token'])))`, even if the token is set in the `$_GET` array that second condition will never be true, because your session has expired, and the token is not set in the session, and/or is not the same to the token in the `$_GET` array.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Well as far as I understand you code, if your session token is not set in `$_SESSION` or not in `$_GET`, just check if both of those are set, if not, error. If both are set, check also that they are the same, if you require that logic.